# Keeping the Hover State of a Li When Hovering Over Another Element

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I have an unordered list of links and hovering over each corresponds to the open state of a separate set of links like so:

```
<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content-area">
  <div class="stuff-changing-here">
  </div>
</div>
```

So for example, hovering over Link 1 shows content A in the stuff-changing-here div while Link 2 shows content B, etc. The hover state of the links disappear when the mouse hovers over content-area and I'd like to know how to keep the hover state persistent. So when Link 1 is hovered, its hover state should persist anytime content A is hovered, and the same for Link 2 and content B, etc. I'm open to using either CSS or vanilla JavaScript, but also don't know what would work best in this situation. Also, if this affects an approach, the hover state of the link involves an after pseudo class when any of the links are hovered and I saw that this can't be controlled in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it, using JavaScript and CSS classes.

```
<ul>
  <li><a onmouseover="show(1);">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a onmouseover="show(2);">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a onmouseover="show(3);">Link 3</a></li> 
  <li><a onmouseover="show(4);">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content-area">
  <div id="content1" class="hideDiv">Content A</div>
  <div id="content2" class="hideDiv">Content B</div>
  <div id="content3" class="hideDiv">Content C</div>
  <div id="content4" class="hideDiv">Content D</div>
</div>
<style type='text/css'>
li { width:auto;}
  .showDiv{display:block;}
  .hideDiv{display:none;}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var itemLength = 4;
  function show(showId){
    for (var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++)
     document.getElementById('content' + (i+1)).className = (i+1 == showId) ? 'showDiv':'hideDiv';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The divs already show accordingly, but the hover is not persisting. I'll give this a try first though, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think you're asking for the visible div to stay visible after you stop hovering?  this should do that for you